# Delete characters from the end of multiple lines in VIm

Tags: vim

I have code similar to this:

```
<%= article.body %></td>
<%= article.author %></td>
<%= link_to 'Show', article %></td>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

I want to delete the HTML tags from the end of the lines in Vim. The only way I thought of was a search and replace. I know I can insert and append text to multiple lines, but is there a way to delete text from multiple lines?

Comment: What's wrong with find and replace?

Comment: @frabjous, nothing is wrong with find and replace, I just thought that if you can add text to multiple lines, you would be able to delete text from multiple lines.

Comment: You can delete text from multiple lines... with find and replace. That really seems like the natural way to do it; it isn't clear to me what kind of commands could be used that would be more natural or require fewer keystrokes, even theoretically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search and replace, after '<', a string of characters not (^) the '<' character, until your reach a '>' that is also at the end of the line:

> %s/<[^<]+>$//g

Correction:

> %s/<[^<]\+>$//g

Comment: The plus needs to be escaped and there's no need for the `g` since it's an anchored pattern.

Comment: Great job explaining the regex, it's really helpful. However, I'm looking for a way to delete characters off multiple lines.

Comment: That's what the % is specifying, that the substitution be done for every line. See `:help 10.3`, `:help :range`, `:help 04.4` and `:help visual.txt` for more possibilities.

Comment: Dennis: thanks for the comment. I've corrected the 'plus' above. I'm a habitual 'g' user, so I tend to stick it in all the time. But you are right -- works fine without the 'g'.

Answer (score 0):

That's one valid method.

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g

```
:[range]g/<pattern>/cmd
```

> An Ex command is one starting with a
>   colon (':'). The command works on the
>   specified range (default whole file),
>   by executing the Ex command cmd for
>   each line matching . Before
>   executing cmd, "." is set to the
>   current line.

This seems an equally facile way to run a command on a group of files.